# Is there a journal/magazine about research?

Tags: research-process, peer-review, funding

I wonder if there is a peer-reviewed journal or a magazine about general aspects of academic research such as

- peer-review
- scientific publication
- the procedure of research funding

Different topics such as higher education are investigated and analyzed scientifically. I am curious to know if there are research fields for the analysis of peer-review process or funding systems.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by *scientific publication* and *the procedure of research funding*? Regarding peer-review, there are certainly articles on peer-review, but unaware of any journal dedicated to peer-review. (Personally, I don't think such a journal is necessary.)